# Circular reference between three classes

Tags: c#, class, circular-reference

I have three classes and I have a circular reference between them.

```
class A 
{
    public A()
    {
        B obj = new B();
    }
}
class B
{
    public B()
    {
        C obj = new C();
    }
}
class C
{
    public C()
    {
        A obj = new A();
    }
}
```

When I create an object of `A`, it's throwing an exception. 
How I can create classes instances circularly referencing each other?

Comment: Circular reference, or stackoverflow exception?

Comment: You could resolve it removing by removing the circular reference :)

Comment: If I ever end up with something like this, I'll review architecture of my code.

Comment: And when object C changes, it tells A, which decides _it's_ changed and tells B, which decides _it's_ changed and tells C, which decides _it's changed, and tells....  Seems a rather common problem (though often with more objects but fewer classes).  And do you create an unusable object, or leak `this` in the constructor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this:

```
class A 
{
    public B b;

    public A()
    {
        this.b = new B(new C(this));
    }
}
class B
{
    public C c;
    public B(C c)
    {
        this.c = c;       
    }
}
class C
{
    public A a;
    public C(A a)
    {
        this.a = a;
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution is not so good as you very tightly couple these classes. The question then becomes, why use different classes in the first place? If you do need different classes you should not couple them so tightly as that you need a reference to this passed into a constructor.

Comment: @JonathanvandeVeen the coupling of the classes hasn't really changed here. Simply: it now works. They were equally coupled before, but with the additional downside of *not working*.

Comment: True, except you're working around something that smells like bad design in the first place, hence I think you should go with a better design.

Answer (score 5):

> When I am creating object of A it's throwing exception

Well yes, it would. Creating `A` creates a new `B` which creates a new `C`, which creates a new `A` etc.

> How could I resolve the circular reference.

Presumably you want the `C` constructor to know about the original `A`? If so, there are two options:

- Construct all three separately, then tell them about each other. This requires the types to be mutable.
- Pass `this` from the `A` constructor to the `B` constructor, and then pass it on from the `B` constructor to the `C` constructor. This is nasty in terms of allowing `this` to escape `A`'s constructor, and should be done *very* carefully. (`B` and `C` shouldn't call any methods on the instance before it's had a chance to finish initializing.)

Comment: Very fast. LOL The answer time and thought process is crazy.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way that is still neat, is to create an interface IA which defines the public interface for class A. Then make class A implement interface IA.
Then add a factory class that can create an instance of A and returns an IA. This way class C does not need to know about class A and the circular reference is broken.

Comment: Adding extra interfaces, an interface implementation, and a factory: doesn't really meet my definition of "easiest". It is a fair suggestion, don't get me wrong - I'm just quibbling the use of the word "easiest".

Comment: Point taken. To most this is easier than implementing dependency injection, though, which would me by preferred solution. The solution where they say to pass a reference between constructors from one class to another is not acceptable to me, so for me that does not count as a real solution.

Answer (score 2):

You could also try and load the objects [lazily](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997286.aspx). That way, they won't actually be constructed immediately and won't get into a circular loop of constructs, but rather be constructed when you actually need them.

You could try using C#'s `Lazy<T>` implementation in the MSDN article, or something involving [properties](http://www.jkillaars.nl/tech/?p=34) by constructing on access with `get{ }`.

Answer (score 0):

When u call the constructor of A,B or C you always will get an exception. Maybe you can solve it by passing a paramter to the constructor, but i'm wondering what you want to do with this structure. Can u tell me please?